# MVC4 ignore fragment / anchors

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having an issue with anchor tags in MVC4. I have a simple page with anchor tags `<a href="#lower">` going to anchor names `<a name="lower">` lower in the page.

However, MVC4 routing *I believe* is interfering and causes the anchor to refresh the page and strangely begin the html at that anchor. (*weird?*)

Anyway, my searching is turning up nothing, I simply need it to ignore it and do what a normal html page would do and scroll down to the anchor name.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: The "begin the html at that anchor" thing: I've seen that when I used a negative margin hack to do equal height columns. The "reload" part: You aren't using `<base>` are you?

Comment: Negative... not using any negative margins on that page.

Comment: Remove all your CSS (and perhaps javascript) and see what happens. Also: `<base>`? Or: What's the URL in the *generated* HTML for the links? Hash fragment only or full url +hash?

Comment: Sorry not using base either. Let me take out the css and try again. Also there's no generated html for the links i just hard coded it and it's hash fragment only.

Comment: So... CSS is doing something... because with all css removed it's not causing this issue.

Comment: Found the culprit.. it's something in fancybox's css.

Comment: Actually... it isn't... the issue is with the column fix I implemented. when you have a *margin-bottom: -100000px; padding-bottom: 100000px;* in CSS to make 2 columns the same height.

Comment: Yep, exactly what happened to me years ago - which is why I no longer use that method.

Comment: Hmmm.... I've been using this technique ever since and highly recommend it: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm